# how to deal with feature that are not change over time when use RNN(LSTM)

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I build a model based on LSTM to predict sale of next day. most of features (eg: sale of day, number of customer) change over time. **but there are some feature (eg: price of item) are not changing**. 
For now, I just feed all these data into LSTM. But I wonder for features that are not changing over time, is there a better way to deal with it? because I think RNN is designed to model temporal structure.

Comment: what do you mean change? Of course, for one particular customer, variables that define this customer at a particular time step might change from one to another.

Comment: yes.  change mean that this feature may change from one time step to another.  but there are also features that will stay constant over time step.